# Unable to download word files

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, rest, sharepoint

We have hosted an asp.net (C#) application on the iis 8.5 server.

The application  is used to download or preview word files and are working file for a while. But then it stopped after the restart.

normally when this happen we just close all instance of the word file and iis then it seems to start working. But today it stopped even after restarting.

it is not hanging, but when i clicks on the link to preview or download, it shows waiting for Website url. but the page is still responsive.

When i check on the Task Manager of the server i can see a word process  (Microsoft Word (32 bit) ) running, and when i close it it stops the website went the way it was before.

Event viewer does not show much on this regards . i used edge and chrome with no luck.

Here us the code snippet for previewing the document

```
if (result != "FALSE")
{
    lblMsg.Text = "CV Created for " + EMPNO;
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(result);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.Name);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}

Code snipet for downloading the document 

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
//System.Web.HttpContext c = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
string archiveName = String.Format("EmployeeCV-{0}.zip",
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + archiveName);
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddFiles(filesToInclude, "CV");
    zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
Directory.Delete(saveLocation, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MIME type to download files

```
    public class FileAPIController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/FileAPI/GetFile")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string fileName)
        {
            //Create HTTP Response.
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            //Set the File Path.
            string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + fileName;

            //Check whether File exists.
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                //Throw 404 (Not Found) exception if File not found.
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                response.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("File not found: {0} .", fileName);
                throw new HttpResponseException(response);
            }

            //Read the File into a Byte Array.
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            //Set the Response Content.
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

            //Set the Response Content Length.
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.LongLength;

            //Set the Content Disposition Header Value and FileName.
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;

            //Set the File Content Type.
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName));
            return response;
        }
    }
```